# Can I use Paypal for recursive payments or for subscriptions in Ionic 3?

Tags: paypal, ionic3, paypal-subscriptions

I want to create monthly and weekly subscriptions in my ionic 3 application and I want to use Paypal for this purpose.

I can not find the proper way to integrate it. Can anyone help? I also want to check the subscription status of the user whenever he opens the application.

Answer (score 0):

From best of my knowledge you cant do this with ionic. Since they just have single payment option available. You can't do this until unless you do some native coding write down custom code.

All you can do this is you can open a your website URL in **InAppBrowser** and from there user can purchase its subscription and once the subscription is successfully purchased you can close the **InAppBrowser**.

I have mentioned PayPal available plugin listed below.

```
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/paypal
```